# assign various rows of a csv file to one value

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, cycle

So I have a csv file with the fields `station, year, temperature` which looks like this:

```
A , 1978 , 27.5
A , 1979 , 27.6
B , 1978 , 25.5
B , 1979 , 25.8
```

My goal is to make a graph which compares Temperature vs. time for various weather stations, how can I group all the values for A to be stored in some X and Y arrays to form a line and then all the values for B to be another line and so on?

Note: the actual file has over 1000 lines and not all the stations have info for the same number of years, so I can't rely on patterns like grouping values every 20 years or anything like that, I'm still sort of new to python, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Answer (score -1):

If you just search 'python csv', the first link would have brought you to something of great use:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

I added the function there to direct you even more but the python csv module lets you do exactly what you want and it's very easy to use. In the example they give for reader, you can also access the variable row as a list for each element of the row just read in.

Comment: Hi, yes I am aware of that module, however I have the problem that the stations are not even letters but just really long numbers, and they're not even consecutive, i.e I am looking at the table right now and it jumps from station `34015010` to station `41015100` how can I look at these in a more automatic way?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how that matters. I mean, you can use a dict and have the station be they key and store the X,Y coordinates however you want as the value. What do you mean by a more automatic way?